# How to pas picklistvalues into label lightning component states Discription undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-object, javascript-controller

I want to pass the picklist values to a label of a checkbox but get error [Cannot read property '$getDescriptor$' of undefined]

Here is my code

apex controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public List<String> getPickListValuesIntoList(){
   List<String> pickListValuesList= new List<String>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opleiding__c.Categorie__c .getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : ple){
        pickListValuesList.add(pickListVal.getLabel());
    }     
    return pickListValuesList;
}
```

javascript controller

```
doInit2 : function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.getPickListValuesIntoList");
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        component.set("v.picklistCategorie", a.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Component

```
<aura:handler name="init2" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit2}" />
<aura:attribute name="picklistCategorie" type="Object" />

<lightning:input type="checkbox" label="{!v.picklistCategorie[0]}" onchange="{!c.Techniek}"/><br/>
```

Comment: Hi @Thomas. Did you check that your `pickListValuesList` array is not empty?

Comment: @MartinLezer yes tried that on the server side. It has values

Comment: Could you add `console.log(component.get("v.picklistCategorie"));` in your js controller to check if the value is right? Just after the line `component.set("v.picklistCategorie", a.getReturnValue());`

Comment: @MartinLezer   The log says: aura_proddebug.js:32947 WARNING: unexpected unwinding of pathStack.  found /* idx 1 expected /$   .I get a popup with:Component class instance initialization error [Cannot read property '$getDescriptor$' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {markup://c:OpleidingListTest}

Comment: @MartinLezer I cant find the reason for this. Does your knowledge go any further on this topic if not thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I can't reproduce your bug. This is working for me. Are you sure the bug is not linked to another part of code inside your component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72287/discussion-between-thomas-and-martin-lezer).

Comment: @Thomas make your code more debug friendly - to your apex code - print the picklist values before sending them, when your `action.setCallback` returns - check if it executed ok - `if(component.isValid() && a.getState()=== "SUCCESS")` and also print the result to see and compare if the values are ok